# Salesforce - Apex Trigger behavior after admin/dev user deletion

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

I'm fairly inexperienced in Salesforce, but a client asked me to look into this so I'm reaching out after not being able to find much on the topic. I appreciate any insight you may have.

The organization had an admin that created multiple apex triggers, and that admin user has since left the organization. I know that there are triggers that handle old integrations, but there are a dozen or so that I have no idea what they do, and the code is hidden so I cannot review them.

The organization wants to delete the user and get rid of the license, but I am unsure what will happen to these triggers if the user who created them is no longer a licensed user in the system. I'm trying to collect as much info about the anticipated behavior after removing the license as possible before moving forward. Again I really appreciate any info/insights you may have.

Thanks!

I've not tried anything as of yet, I'm researching and was not able to find anything specific on the topic in the Salesforce docs, or through google/duck searches.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete the user, best you can do is deactivate (and this reclaims the user license). If you aren't sure you can buy some time by Freezing the user prior to deactivating, it'll block the ability to login.

It doesn't matter who created the triggers, they're executed with current user's permissions (who's creating/editing the record). So should be fine.

Even if the triggers do some weird stuff like contact 3rd party systems, send them the user's session id so the 3rd party can go back to salesforce to update some stuff - it'll run as current user, not trigger's creator.

**There is 1 funny place** you won't be able to check in Setup's UI but it matters only if you have "Setup -> Platform Events" + their triggers. Platform Event triggers by default run as special "Automated Process" user but there's a [special trick to make it run as somebody else](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_trigger_config.htm). Simplest way to check it for a non-developer... If you've never used Salesforce REST API maybe go to [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/restExplorer.php?url=/services/data/v56.0/tooling/query&autoExec=1) -> Utilities -> REST explorer and execute this:

`/services/data/v56.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+DeveloperName,+UserId,+User.Name+FROM+PlatformEventSubscriberConfig`

and check if the results contain this guy's name or id.

**For your all other "what could possibly go wrong" needs** I'm going to send you to my ancient answer at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/24545/799

Comment: Thank you for the incredibly thorough response, this is extrordinarily helpful. I'm going to read up on all of this before making any changes like freezing or deactivating the admin user.

Comment: good luck :) if you have follow up questions maybe ask them on that sister site, it's more admin-friendly and welcomes also salesforce "side products" such as Marketing Cloud, Mulesoft. Technically Stackoverflow is for coding problems and well, you didn't post any code ;) Leaving user (even admin) is a config problem

Comment: will do, and very good point on the code front.